# Line Style Nodes in Blender Internal?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

Is it possible to recreate the Cycles node setup below in Blender Internal? To apply brush texture *along the stroke* you need to connect the color to the alpha. [image: cycles line texture nodes]